# screen orientation like portrait and landscape in iphone

Tags: iphone

Im new to iphone development. here i want to view the screen like landscape porgrammaticaly in iphone. i completed like portrait side now when i turn left and right sides automaticaly i added some images and pickerview data these are also shown like portrait and landscape screens to iphone .

Can any one plz help me for how to orientation the screen programmaticaly in iphone

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this method in your class.

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
  // Return YES for supported orientations

  return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight ||
  interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);

}